# How Insert on table IF some value is in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a syntax problem on Asp.Net when I try to run an insert on a table if I have a vlaue in another table that I look for.

I tried different queries and datareaders but that generates a problem, one of the 2 datareaders needs to be closed.

```
        con.Open();

        String insertRegInfo = "INSERT INTO Login (NumEmp,Nombre,Apellido,Codigo) values (@NumEmp, @Nombre,@Apellido,@Codigo) SELECT NumEmp from Empleados WHERE NumEmp = " + TxtNumEmp.Text +"" ;

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertRegInfo, con);

            LblConfirm.Text = "Confirmado";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumEmp", TxtNumEmp.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", TxtNombre.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellido", TxtApellido.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codigo", TxtCodigo.Text);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
```

I expect to insert data into the table if any value is true.

Comment: Better you create a stored procedure and do everything inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me start saying that this is a terrible coding practice:

```
 String insertRegInfo = "INSERT INTO Login (NumEmp,Nombre,Apellido,Codigo) values (@NumEmp, @Nombre,@Apellido,@Codigo) SELECT NumEmp from Empleados WHERE NumEmp = " + TxtNumEmp.Text +"" ;
```

Better is:

```
String insertRegInfo = "INSERT INTO Login (NumEmp,Nombre,Apellido,Codigo) 
SELECT NumEmp,@Nombre,@Apellido,@Codigo from Empleados WHERE NumEmp = @NumEmp" ;
```

You should use parameters instead and better even Store Procedures.

However, to answer your question. All you need to do is match the number of columns of your SQL Command.

```
INSERT INTO Login (NumEmp,Nombre,Apellido,Codigo) 
SELECT NumEmp, @Nombre,@Apellido,@Codigo from Empleados WHERE…
```

Note that I removed the **`values`** section from the **`insert`**. That is not required

Comment: Dalorzo probably i dont explain better.  The main issue here is... I need to insert in Login Table only if the TxtNumEmp.Text contains a value on Empleados table.    Your recomendation is not work.. im using mysql and bring me some error. Thanks a lot, i expect that you continue helpme with this issue